# In regards to static methods within a project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, static

I have a rather rudimentary question, a problem that popped up after switching my IDE from NetBeans to Eclipse.

In Eclipse, you define a workspace where all configurations and settings are stored. Inside this workspace, I created a new Project, where all resides my classes for one Java lab.

This is the tree:

[image]

Working on the `NoObject`, this is what I have (amongst other things that are not important in the context of this question):

```
static int randInt(int value)
{
    Random randomNum = new Random();
    return randomNum.nextInt(value);
}
```

Using a `NoObjectTest` class, we are told to use the `rantInt()` static method to demonstrate the global principle.

Within my `NoObjectTest`, this is what I have:

```
public class NoObjectTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(randInt(5));
    }
}
```

With this said, Eclipse is telling me it cannot find `randInt()` despite the `static` type of this method in `NoObject`.

Things I've tried are:

1. importing the `static` method from `NoObject` as a class/library into `NoObjectTest`. This didn't work.
2. Creating a constructor stub inside `NoObjectTest`. This didn't work.

What's interesting is, the things I've tried all work in NetBeans. However, migrating it to Eclipse, it stopped working.

Can someone tell me what it is I am doing wrong? Do I have Eclipse setup incorrectly? Currently, each new Project is a new class (class in the college sense, not a programming sense), so each "lab" is a new "project". Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: It's inside the `NoObject` class. I am reading up on other Stack threads, and they suggest switching to either JRE 1.6/1.7. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Are you suggesting for this `NoObject` + `NoObjectTest`, these two classes, they should reside in their individual project?

Comment: It's a problem that only popped up after importing my project to Eclipse. The concept of workspaces are confusing to me, as I didn't need to care about a single all-encompassing folder in NetBeans. But it appears this is a standard within Eclipse, so I had to change the overall structure of all my past code.

Comment: Is it a good/bad idea to put all classes of one assignment into one project? Previously in NetBeans, for each individual question, I had one project, so at max, each project only had 1-3 individual classes depending on the question. It seems in Eclipse, you cannot nest projects. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: It depends. A project is just a way to group classes in order to compile them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call static methods, you must include the name of the class where the method is located. Use `NoObject.randInt(5);`

Comment: Read the whole question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can someone please tell me why this is downvoted?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage This solution is equivalent to doing what you did in `1`. Assuming you did it correctly.

Comment: I didn't explicitly do what Joel did. I simply imported the class, but I couldn't complete it as Eclipse is telling me it couldn't find the NoObject class. I'm going to mark this as the answer, as it solved my question.

Comment: @Sotirios, who knows what he/she did in `1`?  "Importing a method as a class/library" doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I'd like to know also. Feel free to give it an upvote if it solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, @JoelA.Christophel. I'll also mark this as answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a class is in the same package doesn't mean its `static` methods are accessible directly by name in other classes. To make it accessible, you need to import it

```
import static NoObject.randInt; // or all the static members with NoObject.*
```

and use it

```
randInt(value);
```

Or explicitly qualify the invocation with the type name

```
NoObject.randInt(value);
```